# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'gettc' (>= 0) in any repository

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am using Debian 9 and I am trying to install gettc https://github.com/seri/gettc

I have done:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby gem
```

and

```
gem install --local gettc
```

gives me the error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'gettc' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to drop the `--local` flag if you want to install a gem located on a remote gem server and *not* on your local machine.